# Can't get all numbers that aren't dived by 5 to get deleted

Tags: python, list

list=[5, 14, 98, 55]
i=0
for x in list:
if x%5 != 0:
list.remove(x)
print(list)
Only 14 gets deleted, while 98 stays in the list... By now I've tried anything really...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. It creates a new list which only contains numbers divisible by 5.

```
listx=[5, 14, 98, 55]
newlistX = [x for x in listx if x % 5 == 0 ]
print(newlistX)
```